# Py2neo - How do i get node id by node matching?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

i'm using py2neo and try to get node id by these code
and there is no entity["id"], i want to know anyhow to get id of each node.
thank you

`for rel in matcher.match("SINGLE_NODE"):
print("name:", rel["name"])
print("occur:", rel["occur"])
print("pos:", rel["pos"])`

Answer (score 0):

Query for the node(s) using their label and, if filtering, a property. Then you return the node ID and anything else desired.

```
match (n:YourLabel{Property:xxx}) return id(n) as NodeID
```

You can also query by id

```
match (n) where id(n)=12 return id(n)
```

Comment: i try it and the result show up like this "[<Record id(n)=141>]", how can i get only id number. thank you

Comment: It will always return what we have passed as a parameter, isn't it?

Comment: The frst query wll give you only the ID number. "[<Record id(n)=141>]" is the ID in JSON. The point of the second query is that you can get nodes by their ID and then do some subsequent thing with them, like create a relationship, set a property, etc. Of course, returnng the ID doesn't mean much..